# SQL Server Triggers and Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a trigger on update of a table that inserts into another table. This other table only exists in one location (the table is not replicated). If I set the trigger as not for replication, will my update trigger still fire when replicated data comes in to the table with the trigger? That way I can have the trigger and the tables that it inserts into in only one location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: this is the point of [NOT FOR REPLICATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152529%28SQL.90%29.aspx). From MSDN

> - Triggers
>
> The trigger is not executed when a replication agent performs an insert, update, or delete operation.

The key here is "replication agent": this is the process that makes the trigger *not* fire

Comment: Is there a way of accomplishing what I want here without replicating all of the tables the trigger inserts into?

Comment: @JeffN825: Just set NOT FOR REPLICATION on the *replicated table only*. It doesn't matter about non-replicated tables. It is that simple.

Comment: But if I don't replicate the table the trigger inserts into and the trigger fires in a different location that doesn't have the tables to insert into, won't the trigger bomb?

Comment: @JeffN825: I told you it makes no difference. NOT FOR REPLICATION simply says "do not fire if data changed by replication agent". Any tables or objects referred to in the trigger are irrelevant. Just try it. Did you read my link?